# How to install app on apple watch with my version of OS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I can't install the app ,
I am getting an error in xcode :

"error: The deployment targets of your standalone WatchKit app and WatchKit extension must be at least 6.0"

Could you suggest me what to do?

iphone 6 , version 12.4.5 ; apple watch series 4 , version : (5.3)
They both have the newest version of OS.

Comment: What _is_ the deployment target of your watch app? If it's not 6.0, set it to 6.0 like the error message says.

Comment: I am getting another error then "Apple Watch — Johny's watchOS 5.3.4 doesn’t match Weather Apple Watch WatchKit App.app’s watchOS 6.0 deployment target. Upgrade Apple Watch — Johny’s watchOS version or lower Weather Apple Watch WatchKit App.app’s deployment target."

Comment: You need to upgrade your phone to iOS 13 and your watch to watchOS6 or you need to change your watch app to be embedded in a companion iOS app rather than being a stand-alone watch app

Comment: Are there another choice?I have iphone 6 and it doesnt support ios 13

Comment: You can't test a stand-alone watch app on the hardware that you have; You will need to use an iOS companion app to host the watch app or you can rely on simulator testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your phone has the latest iOS that it supports, your watch doesn't - A stand alone watch app requires watchOS6 or later.

To deploy a stand-alone app you need to change the deployment target of your watch app to watchOS 6 and upgrade your watch to watchOS6 (and your phone to iOS 13).

Since your phone doesn't support iOS 13, the alternative is to develop a watch app that has a companion iOS app; this is supported on your current iOS and watchOS versions.